# Gradle is not building boot war

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I am having problem with my project in Java. When I try running bootWar task in gradle on Windows it only generates war for the first time. For the second and later times gradle runs but no war is generated. If I restart Idea, it generates war for the first time again and then nothing. When I was working on Linux (Mint 19 Cinnamon) everything was working OK.

I tried clean task, reloading gradle, reloading project from Git and rewriting gradle files but nothing helped.

**root build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'cz.uhl1k.tcs'
version '0.9.5'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**subproject build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group 'cz.uhl1k.tcs'
version '0.9.5'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'cz.uhl1k.tcs.server.TcsServer'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'

    implementation('org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1206-jdbc42')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
}
```

Thanks for any help.

--- Edit ---

I tried running from Idea nad console with same results. Here is gradle output from build:

```
12:10:20: Executing task 'bootWar'...

> Task :server:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :server:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :server:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :server:bootWar UP-TO-DATE

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date
12:10:24: Task execution finished 'bootWar'.
```

Comment: Did you try running gradle directly from the shell so the IntelliJ plugin is not involved? If that works as expected then there most likely is a problem with the plugin. Also in cases like this, it is very relevant to provide the output that the build generates. You should edit it into the question.

Comment: I appended gradle output into question, tried both cosnole and intelliJ

Comment: "Task :server:bootWar UP-TO-DATE" - I read that as "I'm not recreating the war because nothing changed"

Comment: What do you mean by "For the second and later times gradle runs but no war is generated"? The bootWar task is up to date so generating it again is not needed. This is default gradle behaviour - it avoids to perform tasks again if the output would be the same (caching).

Comment: But then why the previous war dissapears? I am not running clean or anything, it just dissapears. It doesn't generate war after changing the code.

Comment: That's the real question. Apparently the problem is not that the war is not rebuilt, apparently it is being deleted after the standard build process decides that it does not need updating.

Comment: Does the war physically disappear from the build output directory? Is there antivirus/firewall? Or other process that could delete the war?

Answer (score 0):

`tasks.bootWar.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }`

You can add above configuration to have a try, this will force gradle to build the war, the upToDate calculation is wrong sometimes